# Posting metrics to prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have installed prometheus on my Linux PC and I am trying to post some metrics value. I have the following job configured in my yml file:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: test_job
    metrics_path: /metrics

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
```

I would expect the following curl request:

```
echo "some_metric 3.14" | curl --data-binary @- http://127.0.0.1:9090/metrics/test_job
```

to post the metric value, but curl is returning HTTP 404 not found. I have checked port 9090 in the browser and it is used by prometheus, not by some other server software.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: That is not how it works, you do not post metrics to a Prometheus server. Prometheus server scrapes targets (usually where an exporter is running and exposing metrics in [data model format](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/) ) and read metric values from them. To do some quick testing you can try [textfile-collector](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector)

Comment: If you really want to push metrics to Prometheus, although it is not the recommended implementation as mentioned above, you can check Prometheus Pushgateway https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus doesn't support [metrics push](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#push-model) in plaintext format. It supports only metrics push in binary format (aka Prometheus remote_write format) when it runs with `--web.enable-remote-write-receiver` command-line flag. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#overview) for details.

Prometheus ecosystem provides a workaround, which allows pushing plaintext metrics into Prometheus - [pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway). It has [some limitations](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/) though. The main limitation is that it doesn't provide the ability to store **every** pushed metric into Prometheus.

P.S. If you want pushing every metric in Prometheus text exposition format into a Prometheus-like system, then take a look at [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - the project I work on. It accepts Prometheus plaintext metrics via `/api/v1/import/prometheus` http endpoint - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-import-data-in-prometheus-exposition-format).